# memory leak ARC iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

A overview of flow is, application launches with a tableview.On did select row a login screen pop ups in popover view controller.User fills details and logged in successfully.Below are the screen shot of leaks (Leaks by back trace).As i have seen in forums that it is not necessary that leak instruments will show the leak at exact correct place, the leak may have been initiated from some-where else.Below are the screen shots:

[image: full leak]

[image: leak detail]

[image: did select event]

[image: employee login pop up view did load]

[image: employee login pop up view controller initial load called from view did load]

[image: Language module : nsobject singleton class. -getLocalizedString]

[image: FMDatabase stringForQuery Method]

[image: FMdatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray metod]

i have attached all the relevant leak screen shots.if you see there are not % leak showing in instruments.Any comments on how should i manipulate string in -getLocalizedString. This method is reused/called when ever i set text in UIKit objects in view controllers for example ,

```
cell.textlabel.text = [languageModuleObj getlocalizedString:@"not constant string".
```

or

```
NSString *nameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[langmodule getLocalizedString:[[arrSetting objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]]];//alok added memory 14 jan
        lblName.text= nameString;//alok added memory 14 jan
```

Any suggestions,

thanks & regards

Comment: I don't think so its a memory leak. Your instrument screen shot shows just a memory allocation. Don't worry your memory will free up in future after end of scope.

Comment: @Reformer what about the red line oops, i have not attach that but there is red line in leak pane, when i continue running, i got small red lines also, how ever app not crashes..

Comment: @Alok Yes, you are right. It's listening a set of leaks.